# Custom tablayout is null after language change

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-tablayout

I know the question can be weird, but hear me out before pressing the thumbs down button.

I have `TabLayout` of two tabs with a custom view, and I did everything right until I wanted to change the custom tab view when it becomes selected or not, basically, I wanted it to make the selected view's alpha = 1 and the not-selected = 0.3f.

I found a way and it works just fine **BUT** only when the app language is English.. when I change it to an RTL language such as Arabic it gives me a `NullPointerException` when getting the custom tab view.!

**Code** *(check the comments)*

```
private void initTabs() {

    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(adapter.getTabView(i));
    }

    adapter.SetOnSelectView(tabs, 0); // this makes the first tab as selected 

    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int c = tab.getPosition();
            adapter.SetOnSelectView(tabs, c);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int c = tab.getPosition();
            adapter.SetUnSelectView(tabs, c);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}



public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{getString(R.string.tab1), getString(R.string.tab2)};
    LinearLayout main;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_custom, null);
        main = v.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
        TextView title_tv = v.findViewById(R.id.tab_title_tv);
        TextView services_tv = v.findViewById(R.id.services_num);
        TextView products_tv = v.findViewById(R.id.products_num);
        title_tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        services_tv.setText("3 " + getString(R.string.services));
        products_tv.setText("4 " + getString(R.string.products));

        return v;
    }

    public void SetOnSelectView(TabLayout tabLayout, int position) {

        try {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
            // NPE here due getCustomView == null only when locale == ar 
            View selected = tab.getCustomView();
            LinearLayout main = selected.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
            main.setAlpha(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void SetUnSelectView(TabLayout tabLayout, int position) {
        try {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
            View selected = tab.getCustomView();
            LinearLayout main = selected.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
            main.setAlpha(0.3f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return new TabDeatilsFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com._Fragment$TabsPagerAdapter.SetOnSelectView(_Fragment.java:156)
    at com._Fragment$1.onTabSelected(OrderDetails_Fragment.java:88)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1608)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1601)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1569)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.populateFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:1330)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$PagerAdapterObserver.onChanged(TabLayout.java:2850)
    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
    at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:294)
    at com.duolingo.open.rtlviewpager.DelegatingPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(DelegatingPagerAdapter.java:106)
    at com.duolingo.open.rtlviewpager.RtlViewPager.onRtlPropertiesChanged(RtlViewPager.java:67)
```

Comment: add you logcat output please

Comment: @OussemaAroua updated

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33272002/4063532

Comment: @OussemaAroua still the same error.! it gives me null for the ViewGroup now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just solved it.

Your problem is when notifyDataSetChanged is called all the previous CustomViews were reset

what you need to is checking whether the custom view in SetOnSelectView() is null and re-assign the customViews after notifyDataSetChanged.

Hope this helps